# Create Procedure to Insert values from two tables to third one

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have 3 tables as following:

**table FeePlan**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FeePlan](
[FeePlanID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Course] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Semester] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[TotalFee] [int] NOT NULL,
[Remarks] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_FeePlan] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[FeePlanID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

**table StudentRegister**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[StudentRegister](
[Student_ID] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Student_Name] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Course] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Roll_Number] [varchar](30) NULL,
[Semester] [varchar](10) NULL,
[Shift] [varchar](30) NULL,
[Address] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Phone_Number] [varchar](10) NULL,
[Gender] [varchar](10) NULL,
[Email_ID] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Fees] [varchar](20) NULL,
[Transportaion] [varchar](10) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[Student_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

**table FeePayment**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FeePayment](
[FeePaymentID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[StudentID] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[StudentName] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Course] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Semester] [varchar](10) NULL,
[TotalFee] [int] NULL,
[Schlorship] [int] NULL,
[AmountPaid] [int] NULL,
[DueAmoount] [int] NULL,
[Remarks] [varchar](100) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_FeePayment] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[FeePaymentID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

What I need to create is a procedure, when the student details are inserted to table StudentRegister it should compare the values from table FeePlan and insert values from tables StudentRegister and FeePlan to table FeePayment.

Values from StudentRegister table to be inserted to FeePayment are: Student_ID,Student_Name,Course,Semester and with these values compared to table FeePlan values TotalFee,DueAmount are to be instered to FeePayment table.

The Procedure I create is as below but it didn't worked.

```
Create Procedure [dbo].[SP_AddFeePayment]
(

@StudentID varchar(50),
@StudentName varchar(50),
@Course varchar(50),
@Semester varchar(50),
@TotalFee int,
@Schlorship int,
@AmountPaid int,
@DueAmount int,
@Remarks varchar(100)

)

AS

BEGIN

INSERT INTO
dbo.FeePayment(StudentID,StudentName,Course,Semester)
SELECT
      StudentRegister.Student_ID,StudentRegister.Student_Name,StudentRegister.Course,StudentRegister.Semester
From 
dbo.StudentRegister
Where dbo.StudentRegister.Student_Id=@StudentID
END
```

Comment: And what have you tried ?

Comment: So you need the insert in one table to TRIGGER an insert into another?

Comment: You can include your effort here ,then somebody can definitely help you to improve your query and fix the errors on it. and it is difficult to do something from nothing . so better to include your tried code here

Comment: Why aren't you using the parameters of your stored procedure in the insert statement to insert the other values in the table?

Comment: This looks a lot like homework. If your professor is requiring you to prefix your procedures with sp_ you might take a look at this article and share that knowledge with your professor. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Comment: You want values to be compared with table FeePlan. what does this means exactly. Does this mean you want to first insert values into FeePayment from StudentRegister based on parameters passed in stored procedure and then join these values with the table FeePlan. If thats the case then what will be the join criteria